# Form using external php file to show "Sucess"

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this form in a file called "requestaquote.html".

The form is using another file called "requestquote.php" to do it's thing.

Now, this is simple, client will fill in the fields and once a button is clicked, E-mail will be sent.

I need a way to show "E-mail sent" type of thing. Considering my form is using another file to handle the E-mail, I have to redirect back to original page and display "E-mail sent".

How do I do this?

Comment: Posting your code will avoid confusion. In not doing so, risks in someone giving a correct answer, but may not necessarily mean one that is fit for you. The answer that was given below, contains an error in `header`. Please read the PHP.net manual on the [**header( )**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

1.You could redirect from php by

```
<?php header('location:NEW_PAGE_LOCATION.html'); ?>
```

as long as your php code does not produce single bit of html code (even a space!)

2.You can display message from the php script by

```
echo 'email sent';
```

3.You can include another file from the php one by

```
include('NEW_PAGE.html');
```

4.Or you could create the main file, that includes this action file by

```
include('requestquote.php');
if($email_sent) echo'email sent';
```

There are many possible ways of achieving this

Comment: I can redirect, but how do I make the page show an alert after redirection? It needs to show "E-mail sent"

Comment: I'm going to try including the file, and than at the end of it echoing something. Thank you!

Comment: just redirect to the page with "E-mail sent" text in it, eg. 'requestaquote-ok.html'. If you want a full php/html separation. Or use including and prepare html code inside the php script.

Comment: `<?php header('Location: NEW_PAGE_LOCATION.html'); ?>` and not `<?php header('location : NEW_PAGE_LOCATION.html'); ?>` **"No space between Location and the colon"** Very important. Please read the PHP.net manual on the [**header( )**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Comment: @SamFisher To show an alert, [**You can take your pick**](https://www.google.ca/search?q=show+alert+javascript+after+email+sent+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr) - 3 seconds of Googling `show alert javascript after email sent php` wouldn't have killed you, you know.

Comment: @lejlot As per the [**include( ) statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) you can omit `( )` as in `include 'vars.php';`

Comment: @Fred I know how to do it onclick, I just didn't know how to do it after redirecting back to the page =)

Comment: @SamFisher Has your problem been resolved?

Comment: @Fred What problem? I am not the author of the question

Comment: @lejlot LOL! oops, sorry about that. I edited it.